# How to strengthen the Tension of part of clothing

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I will cover the fabric on a curved frame. However, problems arise where the tension of the fabric is not sufficiently implemented, such as:

[image]
[image]

To be exact, I want the fabric not to lean inside the frame and the fabric would stretch out.(like a sky-blue marked)

[image]
[image]

To implement what I want, I have to partially strengthen the sewing tension of the fabric. However, although I tried many ways, including overlapping edges to a verties, was not able to strengthen tension in part.

[image]

Q. **Tell me how to strengthen the tension of the clothing in part.**

[image]